# Pass cookies from HttpWebRequest to HttpContext.Current.Response

Tags: http, cookies

I receive a request in HttpContext.Current.Request on mydomain.com/me.  As part of processing that request I make an API call out to another server, theirdomain.com/them, using a HttpWebRequest object, and receive a cookie back with a domain of theirdomain.com and a path of /them. That cookie needs to be available in the client browser and passed back with future Requests so it can be passed in future api calls, but the HttpContext.Current.Response does not receive a copy of it.  I know I can't manually create the cookie in the Response because I can not set the domain to theirdomain.com in a response coming from mydomain.com, but is there a way to pass through a cookie legitimately set by theirdomain.com?
This is not a one time occurrence because the cookie has an expiration set; each time mydomain calls an api on theirdomain.com the cookie will be returned with an updated expiration value.